# Redirect all aspx pages when not logged in session

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

in MVC I can handler requests before the action be executed (with ActionFilterAttribute or AuthorizeAttribute, and others I think).

If I need to control authentication (Identify if the user are logged) I can simple handler one of Attributes described before and check my Session (presupposing I'm controlling login with Session) and if the user is not logged I just simple redirect to login page.

But how can I do it in Asp.net Web Forms?

Answer (score 0):

One method to go about doing it would be to throw a check in the page load event.  In my case, we're using a masterpage that is the "Shared View" of every page on the site, so each page load checks the user is logged in.

Within the master page we have:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
}
```

We're using [MembershipProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and FormsAuthentication to keep track of users

Answer (score 0):

You can make all your pages inherit from a base class, and add logic in the base class to perform a redirect. This will end up behaviorally similar to MVC filters.

```
public class BasePage: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public BasePage()
    {
        this.PreInit += AuthenticationFilter;
    }

    public void AuthenticationFilter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!User.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/User/Login");
        }
    } 
}
```

Note, I haven't tested this code.

---

Alternatively, you can configure authorization in your `web.config` with the [authorization element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d82143t(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <authorization>
         <allow roles="Admins"/>
         <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

You can also selectively apply authorization using the [location element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178692(v=vs.100).aspx).